# How to save python Apscheduler using SQLALchemyJobStore

Tags: python, mysql, apscheduler

Recently, I'm working on making personal news aggregator on localhost server using `python`. I want to get RSS feed automatically from many different sites at specific time every day. I searched for this on the internet and i found out there is `Apscheduler` library. To avoid creating new scheduler every time i turn on computer, i think it is better to save the scheduler in my `Mysql` database using `SQLALchemyJobStore`.

There is a lot of information related to creating scheduler and configuration at [here](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html) but i can't find any mention about storage and loading. Assuming the code below is the scheduler that I want to create, How can i save and load the `scheduler` variable in my database?

```
from pytz import utc

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


jobstores = {
    'mongo': MongoDBJobStore(),
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
}
executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 3
}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
```

Comment: You needn't to worry about it, it works automatically. There is a simple executable example: https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/jobstores/sqlalchemy_.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Sraw mentioned you do not need to worry about how to load jobs it will do it for you. You forgot adding one line at the end which is

```
scheduler.start()
```

Just do not forget to add job_store when you are adding jobs.

```
scheduler.add_job(jobstore='mongo', trigger='cron', minute=8)
```

In my case I am using just

```
jobstores = {
    'mongo': MongoDBJobStore()
}
```

and it creates 'apscheduler' database in my mongo with collection 'jobs'. You can go and check manually by using mongo shell if jobs are being loaded. You can also use print_jobs or get_jobs() of scheduler

```
scheduler.print_jobs(jobstore='mongo') #mongo in case only
jobs = scheduler.get_jobs(jobstore='mongo') #mongo in my case only
```

Eventually your code will look like

```
from pytz import utc

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


jobstores = {
  'mongo': MongoDBJobStore(),
  'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
}
executors = {
  'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
  'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
  'coalesce': False,
  'max_instances': 3
}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, 
executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
scheduler.start()
```